# Output iTunes library to HTML or PDF

Tags: macos, itunes, libraries, export

I'm looking for a piece of software or a script that will take my iTunes library and give me an output (either as HTML or PDF) of simply a list of all the albums I have, preferably as Artist - Album format. Working with iTunes 9 on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iTunes' printing functionality to get a PDF listing of your library. Just select the main "Music" playlist in iTunes and select Print from the File menu.  Select the type of listing you want (there are a couple different options there to choose from), then when you get to the main print dialog, click the PDF button and choose "Save as PDF". If you use the "Song list" option, it looks like iTunes will print sorted in whatever order you have things currently sorted in the main iTunes window.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XSLT file and apply it to your iTunes XML database. You can then render the output to XHTML or PDF.